# How many 9 letter strings are there that contain at least 3 distinct vowels?

Tags: combinatorics

**Question**: How many 9 letter strings are there that contain at least 3 distinct vowels?

I am studying and I was wondering if this answer could be an alternative answer to the question above:  $$\binom{5}{3}\binom{21}{6}+\binom{5}{4}\binom{21}{5}+\binom{5}{5}\binom{21}{4}.$$

Comment: Three *distinct* vowels?  E.g. does "eeeeeeeee" count?

Comment: No,  they are distinct vowels

Comment: Thanks, I edited in into the question statement, and used LaTeX to encode your answer.

Comment: Your count ignores the order of the letters in the string. (And assumes that every letter in the string is distinct.)

Comment: Is the answer right?

Comment: Generally, it would be somewhat surprising if those two errors turned out to cancel. Specifically, they both decrease the count, so they can't cancel.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is how many ways there are to choose nine distinct letters without repetition that include at least three distinct vowels.  It appears the question allows repetition and considers order different.

To get a numeric answer, I would define $R(n)$ to be the number of strings of length $n$ with no vowels, $S(n)$ to be the number of strings of length $n$ with one distinct vowel, $T(n)$ with two and $U(n)$ with three or more.  Then we have the base case $R(0)=1,S(0)=T(0)=U(0)=0$ and the recurrences $R(n)=21R(n-1),S(n)=22S(n-1)+5R(n-1),T(n)=23T(n-1)+4S(n-1),U(n)=26U(n-1)+3T(n-1)$  A spreadsheet will make quick work of this.